# Directly accessing ColdFusion index.cfm on IIS results in 404

Tags: iis, coldfusion

I have a virtual website running off of IIS (looks like version 6.1, SP 1) and ColdFusion 11.

When I access a page as http://something.example.org/ which uses a ColdFusion template (index.cfm), the page correctly displays. However, when I request http://something.example.org/index.cfm it results in a 404.

Another virtual website on the same server behaves correctly, returning successfully for both http://other.example.org and http://other.example.org/index.cfm

Since I just set up this new website, I'm wondering if there is an additional setting I'm just missing that prevents this error from occurring.

DefaultDocument is definitely not involved since, e.g. http://something.example.org/foo.cfm also results in a 404 even when foo.cfm exists in the root folder. Meanwhile, it finds foo.html in the same folder, so it's definitely not pointing to the wrong place.

Comment: Could you check the "Default Document" for your website?

Comment: "Default Document" must already be set if the `http://something.example.org/` URL works. Might be a ColdFusion connector issue. Try removing and reinstalling the IIS connector for the new site.

Comment: @CarlVonStetten is it possible to remove and reinstall an connector just for that site without affecting the other sites?

Comment: Also, DefaultDocument is definitely not involved since, e.g. http://something.example.org/foo.cfm also results in a 404 even when foo.cfm exists in the root folder.

Comment: It depends on how you set up the connectors initially. If you just chose "all sites", you have to remove and reinstall the connectors to "all sites" again (you're not really supposed to have to do this, but I've always had to). If, instead, you connected each IIS site individually, then you can remove and reinstall the connectors on a site-by-site basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the error was caused because my website's physical path was set to `c:\path\to\directory\` instead of `C:\path\to\directory`. Once I took off the trailing backslash (pretty sure capitalization of the drive letter was a red herring but changed it just in case), the 404s stopped. My best guess is that when you include the backslash at the end, this changes the mapping sent to CF.

I also followed [these instructions to add a virtual `jakarta` directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13993010/coldfusion-10-iis-7-5-getting-a-404-even-though-file-exists#13996743):

> Right click on the website and add a mapped virtual directory named "jakarta" to C:\Coldfusion10\config\wsconfig{instance id} (in my case, it was \1 )

Not sure whether adding the `jakarta` directory is necessary or not, but it definitely wasn't sufficient: the problem was not fixed until I removed the trailing slash.

Comment: The "Jakarta" virtual directory is required for the connector to work properly.